# symfony2 read one column data using fgetcsv

Tags: symfony, csv

I Have csv file that contains just one column, 
I want to read the data in the column row by row
[data in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQEav.png)

This is my code

```
                $rootPath = User::getRootDir() . '/' . $user->getDirectoryName() . '/temp/' . $eti.'.csv';

             if (($handle = fopen($rootPath, "a")) !== FALSE) {
                 $phonexist = false;

                 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000," ")) !== FALSE ) {

                     $line_of_text = fgetcsv($handle, 1000);
                     var_dump($line_of_text);
                     if ($telephone == $line_of_text[0])
                         $phonexist = true;

                 }
                 if($phonexist==false){
                    fputcsv($handle, array($telephone));
                 }

             }
```

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of code can help you :

```
$rootPath = User::getRootDir() . '/' . $user->getDirectoryName() . '/temp/' . $eti.'.csv';

$csv = fopen($rootPath, 'r');
$cpt = 0;

while (($columns = fgetcsv($csv, 0, ',', '"')) !== false) {
   var_dump($columns[0]); // display first column

   $cpt++;
}
```